# Unable to connect between QThread with finished() signal for multiple Qthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a 3 QThreads invoking by one another (all inherited from QThread. I know some might suggest to use moveToThread, but just ignore this fact for now). The simplified code looks like following:

Thread1 class:

```
void
Thread1::run
{
    // some execution
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
    connect(t2,SIGNAL(finished),this,SLOT(onFinished));
    t2->start();

    while(!stop)  // stop was initialized as false
    {
        this->msleep(10);
    }    
}
void Thread1::onFinished(){ stop = true; }
```

Thread2 class:

```
void
Thread2::run
{
    // some execution
    Thread3 t3 = new Thread3();
    connect(t3,SIGNAL(finished),this,SLOT(onFinished));
    t3->start();

    while(!stop)  // stop was initialized as false
    {
        this->msleep(10);
    }    
}
void Thread2::onFinished(){ stop = true; }
```

Thread3 class:

```
void
Thread3::run
{
    // some execution
    QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
}
```

When I have only two threads, it works perfectly fine (e.g. just thread2 and thread3). The onFinished() method seems not connecting with finished() signal properly anymore, after I moved to a three-threads scenario. The onFinished() in thread2 has ever been called. And I am pretty sure the execution of the thread3 has completed.

Can anybody tell me where I could have done wrong?

Comment: I don't see any error in the part of the code you posted. Try using `qDebug()` in order to find out if `connect` returns true and if the `onFinished()` slots are actually called.

Comment: @TimMeyer, I did have print out at onFinished(), but nothing has been printed out. Basically the program has been stuck at the while loop in thread2. But I'm pretty sure the thread3 has finished because I also have a debug printout at the end of the run() method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should note that the default connection type is `Qt::AutoConnection`. This means if signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object's thread, `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used. In this case: `The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.` So you need an event loop.

It works with 2 threads because you probably have an event loop running in your main thread. In your case where you use only `thread2` and `thread3` objects, `thread2` object will actually live in the main thread, while `thread3` object will live in the thread managed by the `thread2` object. So slots in `thread2` object should work.

But in the case of 3 threads, `thread1` object would live in the main thread, `thread2` object would live in the thread managed by `thread1` object, and because there is no running event loop there, the slot in `thread2` object will never be executed.

You can call [QThread::exec()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#exec) in your `QThread::run()` function, but note that the slots will be executed in the thread where your `QThread` object lives in, not the thread it manages. Because of this you shouldn't use slots in `QThread` subclasses. You should create a `QObject` subclass and move it to a thread.

Another option is to use `Qt::DirectConnection` for the connection type, when you connect your signals to slots.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Qt::DirectConnection seems to solve the problem. When you say "create a QObject subclass and move it to a thread", are you referring to using moveToThread method? I might try this method since I am modifying some variables in onFinished() method so I am afraid Qt::DirectConnection might be an issue?

Comment: @JohnYang Yes I am. In case of `Qt::DirectConnection`, it works like a direct function call.