# QThreadPool for large number of computation to be run simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool, computation

I am currently using QThreadPool to run some computation, but however I found out if I throw everything into the QThreadPool, it is actually not performing well and it seems causing some crashing issue. So my idea is to have only a few threads passing into the QThreadPool at once. I wonder if anybody can share some code or example on how to use QThreadPool to handle thousands computation on one PC. I have written something as follows, but I felt it is causing some crashing issue for me at the moment (Class A is inherited from QRunnable):

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    Class* A = new Class();
    A->doSomeSetting(i);

    A->setAutoDelete(true);

    connect(A,SIGNAL(OutputProvider(int))
       ,this,SLOT(OutputListener(int)),Qt::DirectConnection);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(A);

    m_thread_count++;

    if(m_thread_count >0 && m_thread_count %m_maxThreadInPool == 0)
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
    }
}
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
```

And the initialized setting:

```
m_maxThreadInPool = 4;
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(4);
m_thread_count = 0;
std::vector<int> output;
```

The output listener:

```
void OutputListener(int output)
{
    output.push_back(output);
}
```

Is this correct way of doing it or are there any better ways?

Also when setting up max thread count, is the max number you can input in is the number of cores you can have?

I am also using Qt::DirectConnection (there was some issue for me to use QueueConnection) . Will this be a problem when writing to the output listener?

Comment: You must not use Qt::DirectConnection when using threads. If you are having a problem with Qt::QueuedConnection, rather solve that problem first.

Comment: There is no need to wait for threads to complete before adding more. If the number of `QRunnable` objects added to `QThreadPool` is bigger than the maxThreadCount, they will remain in a queue until a thread becomes available.

Comment: What happens inside `A->doSomeSetting()`? If this is where all your calculations are happening, then this is where your problem lies, your main processing should be inside the `A->run()`.

Comment: My problem with QueuedConnection is that I have multiple layer of threads, and it seems I am missing a QEventLoop. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374218/unable-to-connect-between-qthread-with-finished-signal-for-multiple-qthread?answertab=active#tab-top) Do you know any example how to use QEventLoop to help signal/slot connection going?

Answer (score 2):

Qt::DirectConnection may be a problem. As sayed in documentation Queded connection need to be used with threading. See QtConcurrent with QFuture and QFutureWatcher, this class may help you

Answer (score 2):

```
m_thread_count++;

if(m_thread_count >0 && m_thread_count %m_maxThreadInPool == 0)
{
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
}
```

you are waiting every 4 tasks for **all** of them to be done: remove all calls to waitForDone and then you will see an improvement and `QueuedConnection` will work again

you can add more tasks than there are threads the extra tasks will wait until one of the others is done

Comment: So it is ok to create thousands of Class A and just insert them into the threadpool at once? Because each computation will take a bit of time.

Comment: @JohnYang yep totally fine, it'll take a bit of memory but that can be managed

Comment: I am having problem when I removed the waitForDone(). The program crashed after 4 threads were created and 2 of them completed. I also changed to QueueConnection, and it is not helping.