# QThread doesn't emit finished signal

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, signals-slots, qthread

I run QThread from another QThread. 2nd thread's `finished` signal isn't emitted. Why?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, time
thd, thd2 = None, None

class T(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super().__init__()
        self.f = f
    def run(self):
        self.f()

def newThread(f, fin):
    t = T(f)
    t.finished.connect(fin)
    t.start()
    return t

def threadInThread():
    print("Run.")
    global thd2
    thd2 = newThread(lambda: print("Run2."), lambda: print("Fin2."))
    time.sleep(2)

class Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        global thd
        thd = newThread(threadInThread, lambda: print("Fin."))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
f = Form()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect between QThread with finished() signal for multiple Qthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374218/unable-to-connect-between-qthread-with-finished-signal-for-multiple-qthread)

Comment: Paraphrasing the answer of the possible duplicate: The `finished` signal for the second `QThread` is connected within the first `QThread`. This requires the first `QThread` to have a running event loop to process the signal, which it does not because you have overridden the default implementation of `QThread.run()` which calls `QThread.exec_()`

Comment: hmm, moveToThread helps a little

Answer (score 1):

Moving QThread object to main thread works (if we connect `finished` to slot of this object).

```
class T(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, f, finish=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.moveToThread(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().thread())
        self.f = f
        if finish:
            self.finish = finish
            self.finished.connect(self.onfinish)
    def onfinish(self):
        self.finish()
    def run(self):
        self.f()
```